# live/autocomplete search in cakephp 3.x

Tags: jquery, mysql, cakephp, search, assistive

i am trying to perform live search in cakephp 3.x , so far i'm able to achieve it by statically defining the data inside the script tag , i want that the data is retrieved from my MySql database, where all the content is stored. Below is the script tag that i have used inside my Template folder.

```js
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
$(function() {
var results = [
"ActionScript",
"Boostrap",
"C",
"C++",
];
$( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
source: results
});
});
```

```css
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
rel = "stylesheet">
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<!-- HTML --> 
<div class = "ui-widget">

<?php foreach($data as $row)
{
echo $row->name;
}?>
<p>Type "a" or "s"</p>
<label for = "automplete-1">Tags: </label>
<input id = "automplete-1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want the values for the results variable to fetch dynamically from the Mysql database.

Comment: So far i have tried this --><script>

var results = ["<?php echo $row->name?>"]    but it is only showing the last data value , i know that's because the loop has completed it's iterations and that's why showing the last.

Comment: i tried to solve it , and now i know that first i'll have to use JSON_encode , to change the format of the results, and then pass it inside the javascript variable , so is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to extract only names from your $data array. You can do it using CakePHP Hash::extract function (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake\Utility\Hash::extract). Then encode the result to JSON and print it out. Something like

```
var results = <?php echo json_encode(\Cake\Utility\Hash::extract($data, '{n}.name')); ?>;
```